# I need to reference the value of the same object on another value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i have an array of objects. Like this:

```
const obj = [{
   count: 10,
   value: count*2 // the previous count
}]
```

How can i reference 'count' on 'value' without having to find the index, or is a way to find the index of 'obj'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) with a reference to the same object.

```js
const
    objects = [{
        count: 10,
        get value () { return this.count * 2; }
    }];

console.log(objects[0].value);
```